# Method's application on copy of struct is mirrored in original struct

Tags: go, memory, methods, struct, copy

I have been playing around with methods in Go by building a small linear algebra library, but I have run into a problem with the following piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Matrix struct {
    mat    []float64
    nR, nC int
}

func (m Matrix) String() string { ... }

// EmptyMatrix initializes a nR*nC matrix to 0
func EmptyMatrix(nR, nC int) Matrix { ... }

// BuildMatrix creates a matrix build by its rows, and returns a Matrix
func BuildMatrix(rows ...[]float64) Matrix { ... }

// Set sets the value of mat[i,j] to val
func (m *Matrix) Set(i, j int, val float64) {
    if (i < m.nR) && (j < m.nC) {
        m.mat[i*m.nC+j] = val
    } else {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("Index (%d,%d) out of range (0:%d,0:%d)",
                          i, j, m.nR, m.nC))
    }
}

func main() {
    matA := matrix.BuildMatrix([]float64{2, 3}, []float64{4, -5})
    matB := matA
    fmt.Println(matA)
    matB.Set(1,1,2)
    fmt.Println(matA)
    fmt.Printf("%p\n%p\n",&matA,&matB)
}
```

When ran, this is the output:

```
[ [ 2.00 3.00 ]
  [ 4.00 -5.00 ] ]
[ [ 2.00 3.00 ]
  [ 4.00 2.00 ] ]
0xc04207c060
0xc04207c090
```

If I change a value in `matB`, the change is mirrored in `matA`, which is not what I want. In Python I would have made a deep copy of `matA` to start with, but I haven't found any standard Go implementation of Python's `copy.deepcopy()`function. How should I go about solving it?

TESTED SOLUTIONS:

1. `Matrix.mat` is indeed a slice, and I should be copying with `copy(matB.mat, matA.mat`. However, this is not the only problem, since it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: you mean `copy()`? You have a single slice, just need to copy it.

Comment: It's not a slice, it's a struct. Forgot to include the BuildMatrix function, but basically it creates a Matrix with the given rows.

Comment: `BuildMatrix` is not shown in the code, but assuming it returns a pointer, then `matA` and `matB` are both pointers to the same object. It's not so much that the changes are "mirrored" as that they're two references to the exact same object.

Comment: Edited the code to include the header of the function. `BuildMatrix` does not return a pointer. In fact, `matA` and `matB` are in different memory locations.

Comment: @mariohm1311: `Matrix.mat` is a slice, and you need to copy that slice.

Comment: That's not the solution apparently, just tested it.

Comment: @mariohm1311: what isn't the solution? The values are changing in both because it's the same backing array for the slice. If copying the slice still doesn't work, you need to provide a [mcve] showing the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

`matA.mat` and `matB.mat` both point to the same location.

> A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).
>
> https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

When you copy the struct, the copied struct contains a copy of the pointer (which points to the same array segment).

See https://play.golang.org/p/KUWq-dnGMRl

You need to do

```
matB.mat = make([]float64, len(matA.mat))
copy(matB.mat, matA.mat)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZlmFT8toj6A

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Coming from a high-level language, these things keep getting me... Is there any way to avoid having to manually copy every time?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of

Comment: Just tested it, it is not solving the problem. The problem is laying somewhere related to this, but it's not a matter of copying the slices.